# sQl buddy: you have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, sqlbuddy

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'charset utf8 not null auto_increment index key, `toId` int(11) charset utf8 not ' at line 1

This error i am getting when creating a table, USING the SQLBuddy interface..

```
follows:
  id (primary key, autoincrement,utf8) - int(11)
  toId (utf8) - int(11)
  fromId (utf8) - int(11)
```

[image]

question is: why?

Comment: can you post the whole query?

Comment: it doesnt show me, posted screen of settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove the "utf8" settings from the 3 `int` columns?

Comment: This should be a comment unless you are prepared to assert that that is the problem.

Comment: As it turns out this is quite likely the problem.  `charset` is valid only on `char`, `varchar` and `text` columns.

Comment: @JimGarrison: sometimes I get a strange error and cannot add comments nor load the incoming messages (responses) nor logout. While other site functions work ok, like answering or editing an answer (but not deleting!).

Comment: @ypercube if you can reliably replicate the problem you should probably report it on [meta]